# NFS Not letting me edit files except on mountpoint

Tags: linux, macos, nfs

Here's my setup;
NFS server is running Ubuntu Server using nfs-kernel-server.
The client is running on Mac OS X Snow Leopard. I am mounting using Finder's connect to server.

It will connect fine and show me a file listing. I can create, edit and delete files here. However, subdirectories of that gives me an error if I try to save a file, finder does not give me the option to create directories.

Finder tells me that my user has read & write access, my group has read only access to all the files, even the ones I cannot edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem..

To make sure I could write to the files, I'd added a squash in the export, but when that didn't work I decided to change my UID and GID on Linux, then chown all my files. When I was done, I forgot to remove the squash from /etc/exports, removing it did the trick.